# Orientation of Surfaces and Relations Between Boundaries

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

I'm having trouble to interpret something. First of all, I know that the orientation of a surface $S\subset \mathbb{R}^3$ is given by it's normal vector field $n : S \to \mathbb{R}^3$, however I've found something these days that made me a little confused. Well, first of all, I know that if one reverses the orientation, then this is equivalent as taking the oppositely directed normal vector field and so the sign of any integral over the surface would reverse.

The problem is that I've found the following: let $A \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ be some three dimensional set and let $B \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ be a subset of it's interior. Then, if we take the set $A - B$ this is the set that intuitively one obtains by making a "hole" $B$ inside of $A$. The point then is that intuitively I thought with me: ok, that's fine, I'll probably have $\partial(A-B)=\partial A \cup \partial B$ for the boundary of the new set.

However, I've heard that because of this talk about orientation, we have $\partial (A - B) = \partial A - \partial B$. But this feels really strange to me, because what's written there is that the points of the boundary of the set $A - B$ are the points of the boundary of $A$ which are not in the boundary of $B$, however this should be all of $\partial A$ since $B$ is inside $A$.

I don't find a way to justify this $\partial (A  -B)=\partial A - \partial B$, however it seems to be right, since a good mathematician pointed out to me that it had to do with the orientation.

Can someone help clarifying this? Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's happening here is that you're falling into the trap of notation being used to mean incompatible things. When you write $A-B$ above, you're talking about the set difference of $A$ and $B$, also written $A\setminus B$. But when talking about orientation, people will write $\partial A - \partial B$ to mean the union of $\partial A$ and $\partial B$, where $\partial A$ and $\partial B$ are "oppositely oriented".

Comment: Avi Steiner really thanks for making this clearer. I was really confusing the notations. Thanks very much again!